# Prove that if $m,n$ are positive integers such that $\gcd (m,n)=1$, then $C_{mn} \cong C_m \times C_n$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, category-theory

I have a strong hunch on how to approach this problem but I want to ensure before I go forward that this, well, works.

**Here's what I currently have:**

Assume $\gcd (m,n)=1$ and consider $C_m$ and $C_n$. Since $m | mn$ there exists a homomorphism $\pi_m^{mn}: C_{mn} \to C_m$, and likewise $n|mn$ thus we have $\pi_n^{mn}: C_{mn} \to C_n$. Since these groups are all in the category **Ab**, by the universal property of products there exists a unique homomorphism $\pi_m^{mn} \times \pi_n^{mn}$ such that the diagram

[image: 1]

commutes.

Now considering coproducts, the coproduct of $C_m$ and $C_n$ in **Ab** is $C_m \times C_n$, thus taking the homomorphism $\psi^m_{mn}: C_m \to C_{mn}$ defined by
$$\psi^m_{mn}([a]_m)=[am]_{mn}$$
and $\psi^n_{mn}: C_n \to C_{mn}$ defined similarly, there exists a unique homomorphism $\psi^m_{mn} \times \psi^n_{mn}$ such that the diagram

[image: 2]

commutes.

**Now here is what I'm stuck on:**

Since $\pi_m^{mn} \times \pi_n^{mn}$ and $\psi^m_{mn} \times \psi^n_{mn}$ are already both homomorphisms, is it enough to show that they are both surjective then apply the [Schroder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) to deduce that $C_{mn} \cong C_m \times C_n$?

My current "dilemma" with this approach is that (as far as I can tell) I won't be relying on $\gcd (m,n)=1$.

Comment: And now I remember Vladimir Arnold criticizing mathematics in France.

Comment: Let $g_m$ a generator of $C_m$ and $g_n$ one of $C_n$. What is the order of $(g_m,g_n)$ in $C_m \times C_n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $\text{lcm} (m,n)$?

Comment: Aye. So if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, $C_m \times C_n$ is cyclic. No need for even mentioning categories.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't think I understand, how does this show $C_{mn} \cong C_m \times C_n$ though?

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic.  I think that's his point.

Comment: I have never facepalmed so hard in my life. Also, as of today I will never again stay up late at night to do math. Thanks you!

Comment: This is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247135/prove-the-isomorphism-of-cyclic-groups-c-mn-cong-c-m-times-c-n-via-categoric?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: C_{mn} \rightarrow C_m \times C_n, f(x) = (x\mod m$, $x\mod n)$.

First, prove that $f$ is a homomorphism:

$f(x+y) = ((x+y)\mod m, (x+y)\mod n) = (x\mod m + y\mod m, x\mod n + y\mod n) = f(x) + f(y)$

Next, prove that $f$ is injective:

Let $(x\mod m, x\mod n) = (y\mod m, y\mod n)$

Then, $(x-y)\mod m =0$ and $(x-y)\mod n  = 0$

Since $\gcd(m, n) = 1, (x-y)\mod mn = 0$, hence $x = y$.

$f$ is an injective homomorphism and $|C_{mn}| = |C_m \times C_n|$, therefore $f$ is an isomorphism.